# How to load page without refresh using tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

i was trying hard to find solution to this problem but im really lost . the problem is im trying to play video on 1 tab when i move to tab 2 i can still hear the video playing in tab 1 .and if i do click the same tab it doesn't load again . is there solution to this ?

```css
.idTabs {padding-left:0px !important;}
.idTabs li {display:inline;padding-left:0px;}
.idTabs li a {
    padding:5px 15px;
    background-color:#2EA537;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.idTabs li a:hover {
    padding:5px 15px;
    background-color:#805D5A;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.idTabs li a.selected {
    background-color:#42BEF8;
}
.idTabs li a.selected:hover {
    background-color:#42BEF8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://2ytube.com/jscripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://2ytube.com/templates/dark/idTabs-stramaxon.js"></script>
<ul class="idTabs"> <li><a href="#tab1" class="selected">tab 1</a></li> <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li> <li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li> <li><a href="#tab4">tab 4</a></li> <li><a href="#tab5">tab 5</a></li> </ul> <div id="tab1" style="display: block;">  <iframe name="FRAME1" style="width:100%;height:400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xButjfhZWVU" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div> <div id="tab2" style="display: none;">   <iframe name="FRAME1" style="width:100%;height:400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HMjQygwPI1c" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div> <div id="tab3" style="display: none;">   <iframe name="FRAME1" style="width:100%;height:400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xButjfhZWVU" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div> <div id="tab4" style="display: none;">   <iframe name="FRAME1" style="width:100%;height:400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xButjfhZWVU" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div> <div id="tab5" style="display: none;">   <iframe name="FRAME1" style="width:100%;height:400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xButjfhZWVU" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I am begginer in ajax.

Thanks.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AtotheK/pen/LwbKWe)

Comment: I can’t see any Ajax in your code, There is a list that via CSS looks like tabs, the ‘li’ items Contain ‘iframes’ with the videos... what the ‘tabs’ do is just making their content visible or invisible on click, that’s why you can hear the video playing on the ‘iframe’ you’ll have to code for it to stop while the tab is set to ‘display:none’ the reloading is not the problem, your ‘iframe’ is being hidden when you change tab...

Comment: @Atothek if you are using Tab inside any web page please follow this link : https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: is there a way to load only 1 tab at the time not all at once ? thank you guys for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

in your case the section about `player.stopVideo():Void` that explain how to stop a video manually

Comment: i can see what you mean seems amazing but imagine im not using only youtube video lets say any other embed site its  really hard because all i want is to play 1 tab at the time not all tabs load at the same time. you see what i mean? thank you for taking the time to response i really appreciate it

Comment: In this case is better to use, case by case, the specific API provided by the video platform you are using. Just for start you can integrate the YT API and then, for new video providers, find the right way for these use cases